# .htaccess change /es/ to .es

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am working with a domain like:

```
http://www.domain.com/es/blabla.html
```

And I want to change the /es part for .es and convert the URLS to something like:

```
http://www.domain.com.es/blabla.html
```

I've been trying lots of possibilities but I haven't reached a solution.

For example one of them has been:

```
RewriteRule ^es/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com.es/$1 [L]
```

But it has entered in an infinite loop. Which I've tried to avoid adding this lines:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

But the server doesn't allow this calls. So I still have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.html$ /es/blabla.html [L]
```

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't change the url. Anyway, thank you ;)

Comment: I finally have resolved it.

I've put the next: Redirect /es/ http://www.domain.com.es/
And it works fine. Thank for your time ;)